# How do I properly report sighting a drone or hobby UAV to ATC?

Tags: safety, air-traffic-control, radio-communications, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, phraseology

How would one go about reporting a drone (hobby UAV) sighted in the airspace of an airport on frequency, specifically to Tower?

For example: I am doing patterns around the airport when to the northeast of my nose I see an object flying through the airport field, looking as though it is a drone entering the airport. What is my responsibility in this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great question, and I'm not sure there is an entirely established procedure for this yet, as drones are still a relatively new development.

First, your responsibility as a VFR pilot is "See and Avoid".
So if you think its headed towards you, maneuver to avoid it (provided you're not making dangerous, drastic moves!)

Secondly, I'd report it to the tower as:
*"Bay View Tower: N227TW:  I see a drone in the airspace, my 2 o'clock, slightly below, less than one mile, headed towards the airport"*

At best, the tower may be able to say they're already talking to the drone operator.  Otherwise, tower may simply say, *"Roger: keep me updated, deviate from the pattern at your discretion"*

Comment: Is this a hypothetical, or something you actually encountered?  Would you care to share the details?

Comment: For the most part, 'drones' are very similar to the monsters under a child's bed or the 'closet monkey.'  The only difference is a 'drone' is physical to go along with the fear. How many collisions have occurred vs. bird strikes?

Comment: How was this handled before drones ... but after RC aircraft as a hobby started (before WW2)?

Comment: Make sure to carry [this chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VLib.jpg) in your aircraft so you can identify it correctly.

Comment: @TomMcW I tried to make it to through the chart, but it just kept droning on and on.

Comment: @AJHenderson Drones can usually be identified by their more rounded body, larger eyes and the lack of a stinger.